# Joins with multiple table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare  @table1 table (sno int,transferbirds int,noofbirds int,numofbirds int,mortality int)
insert into @table1 

select sno,Branch,isnull((select transferbirds from  K_RT_RetailsDetails  where branch in (PN.sno),0) as Totalbirds,    
isnull(select noofbirds from K_RT_WarehouseDetails where  branch in (PN.sno),0) as Meatbirds, 
isnull(select noofbirds from K_RT_MasterBirdsTransferDet where  frombranch in (PN.sno),0) as TransferBirds,
isnull(select mortality from K_RT_DailyEntry where branch in (PN.sno),0)as Mortality,
isnull(select noofbirds from K_RT_BirdsTransfer where branch in (PN.sno),0) as Tobranchtransferbirds
from K_RT_MasterRetailStores PN       

select * from @table1
```

I am getting error,Incorrect syntax near ','. 1 line,2 line,3 line, 4 line also..please help me

Comment: you can't use `ISNULL(SELECT a FROM b, 0)` you need to put `()` around the whole sub query...  `ISNULL((SELECT a FROM b), 0)`.  Which you start doing for the fist sub-query *(you have the `(` but not the `)`.)*

Comment: now you got syntax error.after fixing this you again get error coz your subquery can return more than one row .why not simple join each table with K_RT_MasterRetailStores PN

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    declare  @table1 table (sno int,transferbirds int,noofbirds int,numofbirds int,mortality int)
insert into @table1 

select sno,Branch,
isnull((select transferbirds from  K_RT_RetailsDetails  where branch in (PN.sno)),0) as Totalbirds,    
isnull((select noofbirds from K_RT_WarehouseDetails where  branch in (PN.sno)),0) as Meatbirds, 
isnull((select noofbirds from K_RT_MasterBirdsTransferDet where  frombranch in (PN.sno)),0) as TransferBirds,
isnull((select mortality from K_RT_DailyEntry where branch in (PN.sno)),0)as Mortality,
isnull((select noofbirds from K_RT_BirdsTransfer where branch in (PN.sno)),0) as Tobranchtransferbirds
from K_RT_MasterRetailStores PN       

select * from @table1
```

Actually the inner select statements are enclosed to parentheses

Comment: Then you inner selects were not correct. If for example the problem is in table K_RT_RetailsDetails it means that you have two rows for the same branch. You can try to use distinct in every inner select if the values are the same...e.g. isnull((select distinct transferbirds from ....